# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)

Tags: android, android-native-library

Someone please help me to fix this issue. Tried all possible solutions provided in Stack Overflow and other blogs. Errors:

```
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0.
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:14.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download carousel.aar (com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-ui.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download numandroidcharts.aar (com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download library.aar (com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download android-image-cropper.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download circleindicator.aar (me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-composer.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-core.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-text.jar (com.twitter:twitter-text:1.14.3)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0.
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download carousel.aar (com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-ui.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download numandroidcharts.aar (com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download library.aar (com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download android-image-cropper.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download circleindicator.aar (me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:14.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-composer.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-core.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-text.jar (com.twitter:twitter-text:1.14.3)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0.
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:14.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download carousel.aar (com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-ui.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download numandroidcharts.aar (com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download library.aar (com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download android-image-cropper.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download circleindicator.aar (me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-composer.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-core.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0)
    ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-text.jar (com.twitter:twitter-text:1.14.3)

Someone please help me to fix this issue. Tried all possible solutions provided in Stack Overflow and other blogs. Errors:

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:14.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download carousel.aar (com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-ui.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download numandroidcharts.aar (com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download library.aar (com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download android-image-cropper.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download circleindicator.aar (me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-composer.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-core.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-text.jar (com.twitter:twitter-text:1.14.3)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download carousel.aar (com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-ui.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download numandroidcharts.aar (com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download library.aar (com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download android-image-cropper.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download circleindicator.aar (me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:14.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-composer.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-core.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-text.jar (com.twitter:twitter-text:1.14.3)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:14.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download carousel.aar (com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-ui.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-ui:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download numandroidcharts.aar (com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download library.aar (com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download android-image-cropper.aar (com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download circleindicator.aar (me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download tweet-composer.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-core.aar (com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download twitter-text.jar (com.twitter:twitter-text:1.14.3)
```

Some of workarounds which I have already tried: 1. To uncheck offline mode 2. Sdk update and changing target sdk and minimum sdk levels 3. gradle version and distribution(url) version should be same 4. Updated Android studio to latest version(3.5.3) and migrated all dependencies to androidx

my build gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/" }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.packagename"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.0.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
   /* implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }*/
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '14.0'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //compile 'com.github.hani-momanii:SuperNova-Emoji:1.1'
    // compile "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.19@aar"

    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.numetriclabz.numandroidcharts:numandroidcharts:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.1'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:4.28.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.0'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:provider:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'

    //Twitter without using Fabrics
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.0'

    //rxjava
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `jcenter()` also inside your repositories and then sync again

```
repositories {
  jcenter()
}
```

Comment: I added jcenter(), and synced. still the error exists

Comment: yeah other projects are working. I checked in other system also. Still the same error exists

Comment: I couldn't see Manifest file in androidStudio

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But is it because of blocking of files being downloaded??

Comment: I think I am not working in restricted environment. Every other network calls, and internet working fine. My system doesn't have any blockage

Comment: Thank You. It worked. I had given like jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
        }. I removed the url and gave just jcenter() in my project level gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

1. add in repositories

   ```
   repositories {
     jcenter()
   }
   ```
2. add these two lines in `gradle.properties`

   ```
   android.useAndroidX=true
   android.enableJetifier=true`
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if the project was working fine before, try to clean your android studio. Instructions on how to clean are in the attached image [click here for instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wL59Z.png)